# Azure SDK List Subscriptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, subscription, azure-sdk

How can i list all `SubscriptionIds` of an azure account?
What i currently have is this:

```
const sub = require('azure-asm-subscription');

//getting the credentials

const subclient = sub.createSubscriptionClient(credentials);
subclient.subscriptions.list((err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

But this returns a `status code of 200` (saying everything is okay), but the array of subscriptions is empty. But their is at least one subscription.

Answer (score 1):

okay i found a solution:

```
const ArmResource = require('azure-arm-resource');

const subClient = new ArmResource.SubscriptionClient(credentials);
subClient.subscriptions.list().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: hey, was it logging the results correctly?
cuz I have two subscriptions, and I get only one.

Comment: Just to update. You should now use `@azure/arm-resources` as `azure-arm-resource` is deprecated. Please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node